# ListBoxFor and EF - Just the first item is posted

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, html.listboxfor

I'm new in MVC and I'm in trying to use the `ListBoxFor`, but I'm not able to post all the selected items, just the first item is posted.

I'm using EF and here is my code. What could be wrong?

### Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.vBSpecialtyTypeId = new MultiSelectList(
        db.SpecialtyType, "SpecialtyTypeId", "SpecialtyTypeName");
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(AddressSpecialtyDoctor addressspecialtydoctor)
{
    db.AddressSpecialtyDoctor.Add(addressspecialtydoctor);
    db.SaveChanges();
    ViewBag.vBSpecialtyTypeId = new MultiSelectList(
        db.SpecialtyType, "SpecialtyTypeId", "SpecialtyTypeName");
    return View();
}
```

### View

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => 
    model.SpecialtyTypeId, (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.vBSpecialtyTypeId)
```

Comment: Is db.SpecialtyType a collection?

Comment: Yes, a collection. It represents a table in my database.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, did you find any solution for it yet ?